# Vampire number generator

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

Inspired by [Reddit r/dailyprogrammer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3moxid/20150928_challenge_234_easy_vampire_numbers/)

> A vampire number v is a number v=xy with an even number n of digits formed by multiplying a pair of n/2-digit numbers (where the digits are taken from the original number in any order) x and y together. Pairs of trailing zeros are not allowed. If v is a vampire number, then x and y are called its "fangs."
>   EDIT FOR CLARITY Vampire numbers were original 2 two-digit number (fangs) that multiplied to form a four digit number. We can extend this concept to an arbitrary number of two digit numbers. For this challenge we'll work with three two-digit numbers (the fangs) to create six digit numbers with the same property - we conserve the digits we have on both sides of the equation.

As always, looking for general feedback over code readability, structure and efficiency. But also I was looking to make the code a bit more flexible.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 6/29/2016.
 *
 * Inspired by r/dailyprogrammer
 * https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3moxid/20150928_challenge_234_easy_vampire_numbers/
 *
 */


public class VampireNumbers {

    /**
     * Calls generate function then displays return value.
     * @param args Not used in this application.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        generate().forEach(System.out::println); // Generates vampires, displays them on screen.
    }

    /**
     * Generates list of vampire numbers. Currently only supports 3 fangs of length 2.
     * @return List of vampires generated along with their fangs.
     */
    private static List<String> generate(){
        ArrayList<String> vampires = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
            String fangOne = String.valueOf(i);
            for (int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
                String fangTwo = String.valueOf(j);
                for (int k = j; k < 100; k++) {
                    String fangThree = String.valueOf(k);
                    String vampire = String.valueOf(i * j * k);
                    if (sortVampire(fangOne + fangTwo + fangThree).equals(sortVampire(vampire))){
                            vampires.add(String.format("%s * %s * %s = %s", fangOne, fangTwo, fangThree, vampire));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return vampires;
    }

    /**
     * Used to sort a string of numbers. Helpful when determining if all fangs
     * are within the generated vampire number.
     * @param vampire String of numbers
     * @return The sorted character list of the given string.
     */
    private static List<Character> sortVampire(String vampire){
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < vampire.length(); i++){
            list.add(vampire.charAt(i));
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }
}
```

It works as of now but can only generate 3 fangs(of length 2) creating vampire numbers of length 6. Was looking to expand the parameters of the generate function to something like:

```
private static List<String> generate(int fangLength, int vampireLength)
```

Also I had a question over this line specifically:

```
if (sortVampire(fangOne + fangTwo + fangThree).equals(sortVampire(vampire)))
```

Instead of concatenating all three fangs, would it be worth it to use a StringBuilder in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also I had a question over this line specifically:
>
> ```
> if (sortVampire(fangOne + fangTwo + fangThree).equals(sortVampire(vampire)))
> ```
>
> Instead of concatenating all three fangs, would it be worth it to use
>   a StringBuilder in this scenario?

Not in this case. The compiler [is smart enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) to replace the concatenation of the String with the use of a `StringBuilder`. Using a `StringBuilder` to create a String from multiple concatenation is typically useful when it is done inside a loop.

For 3 fangs of length 2, your code is straight-forward and will be performant. A couple of notes:

- There is a [mathematical property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17353240/1743880) that could be used to further improve performance. For bigger lengths, it can improve considerably the performance.
- To determine whether all of the fangs have the same digits as their product, you are currently creating a list of characters and sorting those lists to test for equality. You could do that [in a simpler and faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219120/1743880) way without sorting anything.

---

To support arbitrary `vampireLength`, i.e. an arbitrary count of numbers to multiply to make up the final vampire number, we can resort to a recursive algorithm. For that, we will define a method `generate`

```
List<String> generate(int fangLength, int vampireLength, int... previousNumbers)
```

It takes as input the `fangLength` (count of digits in each fang), the `vampireLength` (count of fangs) and the `previousVampires` (array of all the numbers considered so far). This `previousNumbers` will be sorted ascendingly by construction. It returns the list of all the solutions.

- The base case is when `vampireLength` is 0: it means that `previousNumbers` contains all the numbers to decide whether their product makes a vampire number. In this case, we perform the multiplication of all those numbers and compare the digits together: if they are the same then we can build the String representing the solution and return it in a singleton list; if they are not, we can return an empty list.
- In the recursive case, we need to loop over all the possible numbers. First, the upper bound to consider: with a count of digits `fangLength` to consider, the upper bound is simply \$10^{\text{fangLength}}\$. Then, the lower bound: if there were no previous numbers then it is 10 (the starting point); else it is the last considered `previousNumbers` (so the greater). For each of those possible numbers `i`, we concatenate all the solutions by invoking the generate method again, adding `i` to the `previousNumbers`.

A sample code would be:

```
private static List<String> generate(int fangLength, int vampireLength, int... previousNumbers) {
    if (vampireLength == 0) {
        int product = Arrays.stream(previousNumbers).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
        if (sameDigits(product, previousNumbers)) {
            String op = Arrays.stream(previousNumbers).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" * "));
            return Collections.singletonList(op + " = " + product);
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int end = (int) Math.pow(10, fangLength);
    int start = previousNumbers.length == 0 ? 10 : previousNumbers[previousNumbers.length - 1];
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        int[] currentVampires = Arrays.copyOf(previousNumbers, previousNumbers.length + 1);
        currentVampires[currentVampires.length - 1] = i;
        list.addAll(generate(fangLength, vampireLength - 1, currentVampires));
    }
    return list;
}

private static boolean sameDigits(int target, int... numbers) {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    Arrays.stream(numbers).flatMap(i -> String.valueOf(i).chars()).forEach(c -> array[c - '0']++);
    String.valueOf(target).chars().forEach(c -> array[c - '0']--);
    return Arrays.stream(array).allMatch(i -> i == 0);
}
```

Some notes in this code:

- It is using the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to make the code more fluent: the product is calculated by [reducing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) over the array of numbers and multiplying each of them together; the `String` solution is build by [joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) all the numbers, converted to a `String`, separated by `" * "`.
- The `sameDigits` method was rewritten to implement the simpler algorithm of checking whether the digits are the same.

Comment: Very helpful. The code is exactly what I wanted to see and understand it for the most part. Only thing throwing me through a loop is in the sameDigits function. Subtracting '0' from a character makes it an int? or? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Did some looking, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318263/java-subtract-0-from-char-to-get-an-int-why-does-this-work For the people who were not aware of this either. Thanks again